# SQL Server - Create view retrieving most recent value before a given date

Tags: sql-server, view, partitioning

Suppose I have the following table in SQL Server (2012):

```
MyTable:
Date1:     Col1:    Val:
1/1/2016   c1       Val1
1/2/2016   c1       Val2
1/3/2016   c2       Val3
1/4/2016   c2       Val4
1/5/2016   c2       Val5
1/6/2016   c3       Val6
1/7/2016   c3       Val7
1/8/2016   c3       Val8
```

And I would like to create a view that, **for each value in Col1, returns, for a given date, the latest value in Val**

So my view would be as follows:

```
MyView:
Date1:     Col1:    Val:
1/2/2016   c1       Val2
1/5/2016   c2       Val5
1/8/2016   c3       Val8
```

And, more specifically, I could query my view such as:

```
SELECT * FROM MyView WHERE Date1 < '1/6/2016'

Result:
Date1:     Col1:    Val:
1/2/2016   c1       Val2
1/5/2016   c2       Val5
1/6/2016   c3       Val6
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM MyView WHERE Date1 <= '1/4/2016'

Result:
Date1:     Col1:    Val:
1/2/2016   c1       Val2
1/4/2016   c2       Val4
```

---

I can write a nested / cte query to do this looking as follows:

```
SELECT
    Date1
    , Col1
    , Val
FROM (
        SELECT
            Date1
            , Col1
            , Val
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1, Date1 DESC) as version_num
        FROM 
            MyTable
        WHERE 
            Date1 <= '1/6/2016' 
      ) orderedtable
WHERE 
    version_num = 1
```

But I don't have any clue how to convert this exact query into a view where the results change based upon the date queried out or, simply returning the last / latest values if no date is specified in the view-query.

I've been looking into [LAST_VALUE()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231517.aspx), but am not finding that to work either.

Any ideas?
Can this be done?

Comment: Do you want sth like  **[table function demo](http://rextester.com/OYOJ94305)**?

Comment: Wow - @lad2025! - So, I could create the function then incorporate it into the view? I'd need to create some kind of join - I've never joined a table to a function. Could you answer the question showing that? Would it be efficient?

Comment: Btw. You don't need to `ORDER BY Col1, Date1` because you've already `PARTITION BY Col1`. `ORDER BY Date1` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you search for parametrized view. In `SQL Server` you cannot pass variable to view, but you could use [table-valued function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.my_func(@d DATE)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN(
SELECT  Date1
       ,Col1
       ,Val
FROM (SELECT 
        Date1
        ,Col1
        ,Val
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Date1 DESC) as version_num
       FROM MyTable
       WHERE Date1 <= @d 
      ) orderedtable
WHERE version_num = 1)
GO


SELECT *
FROM dbo.my_func('1/6/2016')  -- it behaves as normal table
-- JOIN/WHERE ...
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/OYOJ94305)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════════════════════╦══════╦══════╗
║        Date1        ║ Col1 ║ Val  ║
╠═════════════════════╬══════╬══════╣
║ 02.01.2016 00:00:00 ║ c1   ║ Val2 ║
║ 05.01.2016 00:00:00 ║ c2   ║ Val5 ║
║ 06.01.2016 00:00:00 ║ c3   ║ Val6 ║
╚═════════════════════╩══════╩══════╝
```

**EDIT:**

If you want all values user can pass `NULL`:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.my_func(NULL);
```

Chnage: `WHERE Date1 <= @d` to `WHERE Date1 <=ISNULL(@d, '2099-01-01T00:00:00')`

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](http://rextester.com/NPIUZ68273)**</kbd>

or use `DEFAULT`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.my_func(@d DATE = '2099-01-01T00:00:00')
...

SELECT *
FROM dbo.my_func(default);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo3`](http://rextester.com/GPS85781)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! - But how do I create a view based upon this where the user can specify a date or not - Basically create a view of this joined to `MyTable` on the `Date1` column?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still confused - do you mean there's no way to `cross apply` or anything to make a queryable view?

Comment: @JohnBustos So do you want to build a view a top of table-valued function? The whole point is to use function instead of view.

Comment: Yes, I need a view since my original table has more columns (this is just a simple example) and they may still want to query for another column, for example `select * from myview where col3 = 'xxx'`) - In your example, they would always need to specify a date variable - I'm wondering if they can just deal with a table the whole way through.